# Disabling left navigation panel not working across all SO community

Tags: support, left-navigation

I disabled my left navigation from my preferences in https://stackoverflow.com. But, left pane is still visible, when I browser at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

How to **disable** **globally** across all Stack Overflow community ? Or is it a bug ?

Comment: I just tried It is working for me. Left panel is no more visible after my preference settings.

Comment: @Dsmagento : For me, issue is still there. Please check both of the site settings.